# First "programs" in a non-web environment

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm starting to re-skill myself in Desktop applications. I've been doing Web applications for a few years now.

I've got come decent C# books that I am going through, but they are more like language references. What I would like is a list/site/book with practical exercises, preferably graded in terms of difficulty.

They don't necessarily have to be from a C# site, either, but that would of course be advantageous.

Do you know of any resources like this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a lot of good C# tutorials on [C# Practical Learning](http://www.functionx.com/csharp/), ranging across several topics.

I also recommend [Head First C#](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596514822/) if you want to try a non-reference book.

Answer (score 1):

On the topic of learning C# language itself and the runtime, I would recommend the [Learn C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336766.aspx) section on the MSDN. There are links to lot of articles and trining materials abtou C#. You can combine this with Jesse Liberty's [Learning C# 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596521065).

On the topic of desktop programming, the answer depends on what platform you would like to use.

If you want to target WPF, I'd recommend Petzold's [Applications = Data + Markup](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596510373). (As a side note, learning WPF would give you the basis to learning about RIA with Silverlight)

If you want to target WinForms... well, I am biased and would recommend against. But if you insist, Petzold's [Programming Microsoft Windows Forms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621535) is another good book. :-) Chris Sells' [Windows Forms 2.0 Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321267966) also is very good book about WinForms.

The WindowsClient.net [Get Started](http://windowsclient.net/getstarted/) and [Learn](http://windowsclient.net/learn/) sections have a lot of training videos, articles, FAQ and samples for both WinForms and WPF. The [Community Books](http://windowsclient.net/Community/books.aspx) section also has an extensive list of books on both technologies.

Comment: For WPF I'd disagree on the book recommendation. Petzold's book is too much of a giant monolith for someone new to desktop applications to find useful. Petzold obviously has immense knowledge on the subject, but he's really not the easiest author to read. ;)